# PrologSWI - PathFinding

Tags: prolog

I want to find the path from station A to station B, which is sort of working however, the path I come up with is all over the place, it sometimes goes back and forth between two stations which are off course, comes back to the previous point and then goes beyond station B and back to it, giving me duplicates and unwanted stations in the path.

One thing I noticed might be the problem that some stations are interchange stations with the same name but a different line on them. These are the arc'd stations:

```
%adjecent stations %

% Central line

adjacent(nh,lg,central,4).
adjacent(lg,oc,central,4).
adjacent(oc,tc,central,4).
adjacent(tc,cl,central,4).
adjacent(cl,ls,central,4).
adjacent(ls,bg,central,4).

% Victoria Line
adjacent(br,vi,victoria,4).
adjacent(vi,oc,victoria,4).
adjacent(oc,ws,victoria,4).
adjacent(ws,kx,victoria,4).
adjacent(kx,fp,victoria,4).

% Northern Line
adjacent(ke,em,northern,4).
adjacent(em,tc,northern,4).
adjacent(tc,ws,northern,4).
adjacent(ws,eu,northern,4).

% Metropolitan Line
adjacent(al,ls,metropolitan,4).
adjacent(ls,kx,metropolitan,4).
adjacent(bs,fr,metropolitan,4).

% Bakerloo Line
adjacent(ec,em,bakerloo,4).
adjacent(em,oc,bakerloo,4).
adjacent(oc,pa,bakerloo,4).
adjacent(pa,wa,bakerloo,4).
```

... and here's the rule:

```
next(X,Y,L):-adjacent(X,Y,L,_).
next(X,Y,L):-adjacent(Y,X,L,_).
direct_connect(X,Y,L,S,F):-
                next(X,Z,L),
                not(member(Z,S)),
                direct_connect(Z,Y,L,[Z|S],F).
direct_connect(X,Y,L,S,[Y|S]):- next(X,Y,L).
one_change(X,Y,L,F):-
                direct_connect(X,Z,L,[X],F1),
                direct_connect(Z,Y,L2,[Z|F1],F),
                L\=L2.
exist(X):-next(X,_,_).
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-member(X,T).

route(X,Y,F):-exist(X),exist(Y),
              direct_connect(X,Y,_,[X],F),
              write('Direct Connection'),nl,
              revwrite(F).

route(X,Y,F):-exist(X),exist(Y),
              one_change(X,Y,_,F),
              write('One change required'),nl,
              revwrite(F).

revwrite([X]):-write(X).
revwrite([H|T]):-revwrite(T), write('->'),write(H).
```

With the test case of:

```
route(em,ls,Route).
```

... the output I get is:

```
One change required
em->tc->ws->tc->tc->cl->ls->bg->ls
Route = [ls, bg, ls, cl, tc, tc, ws, tc, em]
```

I do not understand why I am getting duplicates. How can I avoid the path from going off-course, coming back, and going all over the place?

Comment: @JimAshworth: This question is not specific to SWI, therefore its tag does not fit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (one problem, at least) is in `direct_connect/5`; in the following clause

```
direct_connect(X,Y,L,S,F):-
                next(X,Z,L),
                not(member(Z,S)),
                direct_connect(Z,Y,L,[Z|S],F).
```

you don't impose that `Z` is different from `Y`.

Suggestion: modify it as follows, imposing `Z \= Y`

```
direct_connect(X,Y,L,S,F):-
                next(X,Z,L),
                Z \= Y,
                not(member(Z,S)),
                direct_connect(Z,Y,L,[Z|S],F).
```